# Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory

Tags: magento2, permissions, linux

Environment: Magento2 2.2.5 / PHP 7.0.28

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Can't create directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/ResourceConnection/. in [Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy] in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:115 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\Framewo...') #1 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\Framewo...') #2 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Procfit-Institucional/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 115

I already tried:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R on my root project 
sudo chmod -R 777  var/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to launch in your magento directory :

`sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`

It will fix perm like Magento documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Give permission to generated folder

```
chmod 777 -Rf generated/* var/*
```

After flush cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you for comment, i tried that but still the same error

Comment: updated answer please try this

Comment: It still the same error, i gave permissions for generated/* , var/*

Answer (score 0):

Give permissions to the generated folder

Steps:

1. Go To - `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs`
2. `sudo chmod 777 -R magento` (or Your Package folder name).

Then Check